# gridview AJAX paging, sorting with images

Tags: asp.net

Can someone point me to a tutorial that shows how sorting is done with small images showing the sort direction. I'm using linq-to -sql so I'd like something that shows how dynamic linq works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you?

[Moving records up and down with Linq to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057227/moving-records-up-and-down-with-linq-to-sql)